# Ошибка "Встречено else, ожидалось ;"

Tags: pascal

```
var x,y: array [1..10000] of integer;
u,t,i,N,S,max3,min3:integer;
begin readln (N);
for i:=1 to N do
readln (x[i],y[i]);
s:=0; max3:=0; min3:=maxint;
for i:=1 to N do begin 
if x[i]>y[i] then t:=x[i]; u:=y[i]
else t:=y[i]; u:=x[i] end; // <<< --- ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ! ПОМОГИТЕ!
s:=s+t;
if (u mod 3<>0) and (u>max3) then
max3:=t;
if (t mod 3=0) and (t<min3) then
min3:=t;
end;
if S mod 3<>0 then writeln (s) else begin
if (max3=0) or (min3=maxint) then
writeln (0) else
writeln (s-min3+max3)
end.
```

Comment: необходимо ознакомиться с понятием "блок" в императивных языках. Также правила оформления кода "лесенка", будут полезны, в том числе, чтобы избежать подобных ошибок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если банально код отформатировать корректно, например, так, то видно, где ошибка (и не одна):

```
var 
  x, y: array [1..10000] of integer;
  u, t, i, N, S, max3, min3 : integer;
begin 
  readln (N);
  for i := 1 to N do
    readln (x[i],y[i]);
  s := 0; 
  max3 := 0; 
  min3 := maxint;
  for i := 1 to N do 
    begin 
      if x[i] > y[i] then 
        t:=x[i]; 
      u:=y[i]
      else // <<< --- ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ! ПОМОГИТЕ!
        t:=y[i]; 
      u:=x[i] 
    end;
    s:=s+t;
    if (u mod 3<>0) and (u>max3) then
      max3:=t;
    if (t mod 3=0) and (t<min3) then
      min3:=t;
end;
if S mod 3<>0 then 
  writeln (s) 
else 
  begin
    if (max3=0) or (min3=maxint) then
      writeln (0) 
    else
      writeln (s-min3+max3)
end.
```

А теперь корректно:

```
var 
  x, y: array [1..10000] of integer;
  u, t, i, N, S, max3, min3 : integer;
begin 
  readln (N);
  for i := 1 to N do
    readln (x[i],y[i]);
  s := 0; 
  max3 := 0; 
  min3 := maxint;
  for i := 1 to N do 
    begin 
      if x[i] > y[i] then 
        begin
          t:=x[i]; 
          u:=y[i]; // <-- Тут
        end
      else 
        begin 
          t:=y[i]; 
          u:=x[i]; // <-- и тут...
        end; 
      s:=s+t;
      if (u mod 3<>0) and (u>max3) then
        max3:=t;
      if (t mod 3=0) and (t<min3) then
        min3:=t;
    end; //for i...
  if (S mod 3)<>0 then
    writeln (s) 
  else 
    begin
      if (max3=0) or (min3=maxint) then
        writeln (0) 
      else
        writeln (s-min3+max3);
    end; //<--- нужно было добавить
end.
```

Вроде всё.
Используйте операторные скобки `begin..end` не стесняясь, и не ленитесь делать отступы (лесенку), это не зря придумано ведь.

Comment: Блин, что бы я без вас делал! Спасибо, приму к сведению!

Answer (score 3):

После оператора `then` должен идти всего один оператор. Если нужно несколько, их нужно поместить внутрь составного оператора `begin...end`

```
if x[i]>y[i] then  
begin
    t:=x[i]; u:=y[i];
end
else begin
    t:=y[i]; u:=x[i]; 
end;
```

Comment: и это правильный ответ)

Comment: @4per, внезапно :-)

Comment: Огоооо, спасибо большое!

Comment: Если бы не вы, неизвестно сколько бы я ломал свою голову в поисках решения. Правда там ещё остались ошибки, но незначительные! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа должна выглядеть вот таким образом. Вы забыли очень простую вещь: когда вы выполняете несколько действий под одним условием (в вашем случае `if`), то они должны быть между `begin` .. `end`

Рабочий вариант вашей программы:

```
var x,y: array [1..10000] of integer;
u,t,i,N,S,max3,min3:integer;
begin readln (N);
for i:=1 to N do
readln (x[i],y[i]);
s:=0; max3:=0; min3:=maxint;
for i:=1 to N do begin 
   if x[i]>y[i] then
     begin 
      t:=x[i]; u:=y[i];
     end
   else 
     begin
      t:=y[i]; u:=x[i];
     end;
 end;
s:=s+t;
if (u mod 3<>0) and (u>max3) then
max3:=t;
if (t mod 3=0) and (t<min3) then
min3:=t;
end;
if S mod 3<>0 then writeln (s) else 
    if (max3=0) or (min3=maxint) then
      writeln (0) 
    else
     writeln (s-min3+max3);     
end.
```

Comment: `if S mod 3<>0 then writeln (s) else 
  begin` еще отсутствует закрывающий `end;`

Comment: @Embedder скорее не так, там вообще не нужен этот begin, потому что вложенный if - по сути 1 действие :)

Comment: Если так "перефразировать", то да - не нужен. И не забыть после  `writeln (s-min3+max3)` поставить `;`.

Comment: @Embedder а мне кажется скомпилится без неё

Comment: @4per В принципе, да -  перед `end` `;` можно не ставить, но так как-то не по "феншую" :)

Answer (score -3):

Ну русским же языком написано, что надо перед else (в конце предыдущей команды) поставить точку с запятой
`u:=y[i];`

Comment: нет. не надо. ошибка не в этом.

Comment: Ну я уже так делал, ошибку всё равно выдает, но перед else же не ставится точка с запятой?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?